# fixed function vs shader based

Tags: graphics, shader

I'm a beginner to computer graphics and am trying to get a better understanding. My professor has discussed fixed function pipeline and shader based programming. How do these two compare to each other? What's the difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fixed-function pipeline is as the name suggests — the functionality is fixed. So someone wrote a list of different ways you'd be permitted to transform and rasterise geometry, and that's everything available. In broad terms, you can do linear transformations and then rasterise by texturing, interpolate a colour across a face, or by combinations and permutations of those things. But more than that, the fixed pipeline enshrines certain deficiencies.

For example, it was obvious at the time of design that there wasn't going to be enough power to compute lighting per pixel. So lighting is computed at vertices and linearly interpolated across the face.

There were some intermediate extensions related to specific effects — dot3 plus cubemaps for per-pixel lighting from a single source, for example — but the programmable pipeline lets you do whatever you want at each stage, giving you complete flexibility.

In the first place that allowed better lighting, then better general special effects (ripples on reflective water, imperfect glass, etc), and more recently has been used for things like deferred rendering that flip the pipeline on its end.

All support for the fixed-functionality pipeline is implemented by programming the programmable pipeline on hardware of the last decade or so. The programmable pipeline is an advance on its predecessor, afforded by hardware improvements.

Answer (score 12):

Graphics Processing Units started off very simply with fixed functions, that allowed for quick 3D maths (much faster than CPU maths), and texture lookup, and some simple lighting and shading options (flat, phong, etc).

These were very basic but allowed the CPU to offload the very repetitive tasks of 3D rendering to the GPU.  Once the Graphics was taken away from the CPU, and given to the GPU, Games made a massive leap forward.

It wasn't long before the fixed functions needed to be changed to assembly programs and soon there was demand for doing more than simple shading, basic reflections, and single texture maps offered by the fixed function GPUs.

So the 2nd breed of GPU was created, this had two distinct pipelines, one that processed vertex programs and moved verts around in 3D space, and the shader programs that worked with pixels allowing multiple textures to be merged, and more lights and shades to be created.

Now in the latest form of GPU all the pipes in the card are generic, and can run any type of GPU assembler code.  This increased in the number of uses for the pipe - they still do vertex mapping, and pixel color calculation, but they also do geometry shaders (tessellation), and even Compute shaders (where the parallel processor is used to do a non-graphics job).

So fixed function is limited but easy, and now in the past for all but the most limited devices.  Programmable function shaders using OpenGL (GLSL) or DirectX (HLSL) are the de-facto standard for modern GPUs.

Answer (score 5):

Essential the fixed function pipeline is a hardwired implementation of a, well, fixed program, through which each piece of data a GPU processes traverses, without the ability to change the details of any step. The only thing you can parameterize are the occasional branch to switch between hardcoded paths in the program (like enabling or disabling lighting, or using a separate specular) or some constants used (light colors and positions, texture environment base color modulation). And each and every step follows a specific formula.

In a programmable pipeline however the GPU is clean slate. It's completely up to the programmer how the various stages of the rendering process (vertex transformation, tesselation, fragment processing) are carried out. And you can use whatever formula you see fit for the task.

Fixed function pipeline GPUs have exactly one illumination mode: A Lambertian illumination model, implemented using Gourad or Phong shading. There were a few tricks to slightly alter the illumination model, for example to be anisotropic, but you had to somehow outsmart (or outdumb to be hones) the GPU for this. With a programmable pipeline you simply do what you wanted to do in the first place.